# MS Visual Studio 2019 Template ASP NET web application runs in development environment but not in the web server production

Tags: c#, .net, server, production

Production server configured for asp net 4.5 version and TRUST LEVEL MEDIUM.

Messagem error from the server:

> Server Error in Application '/'. configuration error Description: An
> error occurred while processing a configuration file required to
> service this request. Examine the specific details of the error and
> modify this configuration file accordingly.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not find CodeDom provider type
> "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider,
> Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error on the server. The current custom error settings
> for this application prevent remote viewing of application error
> details (for security reasons). However, they could be displayed by
> browsers running on the local server.
>
> Source File: d:\web\localuser\iotsol\www\news\web.config Line: 55
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
> ASP.NET version:4.7.3930.0

I have tried to publish a simple template asp net example in a production web server. I was expecting to see the main web page of the sample but server send me an error message.

Answer (score 0):

With the very tiny information about both environments(development/production) is hard to help you but I can suggest remembering that depending on the operating system you are running your application, system paths can be represented as strings differently.

```
    linux: "./src/Folder" using '/' 

    windows: "C:\\Users\\UerFolder" using '\' 
    but needing to escape because it is special char so effectively '\\'
```

Comment: both OS are Windows and the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform DLL is inside \bin folder.